# Why can I add a horizontal loop cut, but I can't add a vertical loop cut

Tags: mesh, loop

In the images **I'm trying to add a loop cut vertically through the rectangles, however, it only allows me to add a horizontal loop cut**.  The mesh is only a plane and I am using the mirror modifier.  I'm not sure if the mirror modifier is somehow messing it up or if it's something else.  Also, the mesh is part of a larger mesh that I have hidden, not sure if that helps or not either.  I've already tried removing any duplicate vertices and such but to no avail. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?
[image]

[image: Front View:]

[image: No matter where I place my cursor, it only allows me to add a horizontal loop cut.]

Comment: you can't make a loop cut on an ngon (a polygon with more than 4 vertices.

Comment: @cegaton it's not an ngon, it has exactly 4 vertices. I only want the loop cut to be within the rectangle, not the whole mesh.

Comment: @MrZak My question was how to make a loop cut vertical not to continue the horizontal loop cut.

Comment: Hard to say from screenshot in edge selection mode then. It could be due to hidden geometry. Note that hiding geometry doesn't make visible one available for loopcut if hidden one somehow prevents from it.

Comment: maybe share your mesh or at least the part of it with the problem (make sure that if you delete a part the problem still persist): https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/